# Two problems: form input is larger than the dropdown select, and plus icon in the form input is not centered

Tags: css, select, centering

I have two problems:

1. **Form input is larger than the dropdown select:** I have tried changing the height to the select dropdown (in the CSS file), but that did not work. I did like this: `height: 1000` to test it, but it didn't work. (By the way, I did this to `select` in select.css)
2. **Plus icon in the form input is not centered:** I have no idea on what to do to center this. I tried `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` to `form button` in form.css

**Select (CSS file)**

```
.select {
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

select {
  color: #36d1dc;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 12rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Form (CSS file)**

```
form input,
form button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;

  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

form button {
  color: #36d1dc;
  background: #f7fffe;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 0px;

  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

form button:hover {
  background: #36d1dc;
  color: white;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FBgl.png)

If you need anymore information, or if my question was poorly phrased, please tell me. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question; please do not just refer us to external code repositories.

Comment: Okay, thanks @CBroe. I will add some of my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add / Edit these values to your CSS

1. Open Select.css and edit

   ```
   form button {  
      display: flex;
      align-self: stretch;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
   ```

   Remove `min-height: 20vh` from Header and Form
2. Open Select.css

   ```
    .select{
      margin: 0rem 1rem;
      align-self: stretch;
    }

    select{
     height: 100%;
    }

   .select::after {
     padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
    }
   ```

These changes will make the UI Like this
[image]

Comment: Hi Arjun, I edited my CSS files. [This](https://pastecode.io/s/yeKT5V5i9a) is my `forms.css` file. At the bottom of the file there is the `form button` block, (and by the way, I have separated your code so it is easier to see, as I put it at the bottom of the block), and my result is that the plus button is very tall.  [This link](https://pastecode.io/s/V9AeC7Q7T6) is `select.css` (by the way, I also have `.select`, `select` and `.select::after` at the bottom of the file). What I get is that the dropdown is also very tall. [Image](https://ibb.co/3smJxcS)

Comment: What did I do wrong? I have checked my code a few times, and all I notice is the `align-self: stretch` that makes it big. But if I comment out that line of code, it will just become a little smaller than the input bar.

Comment: Did you remove the min-height: 20vh? i can still see that code in your css.

Comment: Thank you so much Arjun! That worked, I had done this 2 times and forgot to remove that part. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. If it solved your problem please make this as an accepted answer, it will help me.